# SQL SUM function giving incorrect values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written this code and I'm finding that the values are in the thousands when they should be only in the hundreds at most.

```
SELECT
    C.CLIENTID,
    SUM(NVL(B.FEE, 0)) AS TICKETS,
    SUM(NVL(PU.QTY, 0) * NVL(P.PRICE, 0)) AS MERCH,
    SUM(NVL(B.FEE, 0) + (NVL(P.PRICE, 0) * NVL(PU.QTY, 0))) AS Total
FROM 
    CLIENT C
    LEFT JOIN BOOKINGS B ON B.CLIENTID = C.CLIENTID
    LEFT JOIN PURCHASE PU ON PU.CLIENTID = C.CLIENTID
    LEFT JOIN PRODUCT P ON P.PRODUCTID = P.PRODUCTID
GROUP BY 
    C.CLIENTID
ORDER BY 
    C.CLIENTID ASC;
```

These are the results i am getting.

```
+----------+---------+-------+--------+
| CLIENTID | TICKETS | MERCH | TOTAL  |
+----------+---------+-------+--------+
| 1        | 0       | 0     | 0      |
+----------+---------+-------+--------+
| 2        | 13650   | 0     | 13650  |
+----------+---------+-------+--------+
| 3        | 17325   | 0     | 17325  |
+----------+---------+-------+--------+
| 4        | 40950   | 20316 | 61266  |
+----------+---------+-------+--------+
| 5        | 91875   | 71106 | 162981 |
+----------+---------+-------+--------+
| 6        | 0       | 0     | 0      |
+----------+---------+-------+--------+
| 7        | 4200    | 0     | 4200   |
+----------+---------+-------+--------+
| 8        | 17850   | 6772  | 24622  |
+----------+---------+-------+--------+
| 9        | 8400    | 0     | 8400   |
+----------+---------+-------+--------+
| 10       | 8400    | 0     | 8400   |
+----------+---------+-------+--------+
| 11       | 12600   | 0     | 12600  |
+----------+---------+-------+--------+
| 12       | 8925    | 3386  | 12311  |
+----------+---------+-------+--------+
| 13       | 8925    | 3386  | 12311  |
+----------+---------+-------+--------+
| 14       | 4200    | 0     | 4200   |
+----------+---------+-------+--------+
| 15       | 17325   | 0     | 17325  |
+----------+---------+-------+--------+
| 16       | 105000  | 91422 | 196422 |
+----------+---------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: what is your table schema?

Comment: I think this is Oracle. Please tag your question properly.

Comment: Why do people tag multiple RDBMS? `mysql` and `sql-server`? + How can we proceed without input data shown?

Comment: Please elaborate reasons for your assumption "hundreds instead of thousands", maybe by providing a [mcve] including relevant sample input. Please consider taking the [tour].

Comment: Sorry if i formated this question wrong.

@InnovaITveSolutions Sorry for not replying didn't see this feed under the question till now

Comment: @FelixPamittan Didn't know there was a difference till now very new to all of this

Comment: @niksofteng I apologize i was unaware that there was a difference, i assumed they where just different ways of writing the code. Such as using Code or a program such as MS Access

Comment: @Yunnosch In the future i will aim to be more precise

Comment: Your results look perfect to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what your tables are but try inner join

```
SELECT
    C.CLIENTID,
    SUM(NVL(B.FEE, 0)) AS TICKETS,
    SUM(NVL(PU.QTY, 0) * NVL(P.PRICE, 0)) AS MERCH,
    SUM(NVL(B.FEE, 0) + (NVL(P.PRICE, 0) * NVL(PU.QTY, 0))) AS Total
FROM 
    CLIENT C
    INNER JOIN BOOKINGS B ON B.CLIENTID = C.CLIENTID
    INNER JOIN PURCHASE PU ON PU.CLIENTID = C.CLIENTID
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT P ON P.PRODUCTID = P.PRODUCTID
GROUP BY 
    C.CLIENTID
ORDER BY 
    C.CLIENTID ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Helped me a lot to debug and find the solution

Answer (score 0):

A solution to anyone who may come across this with the same issue as me is;

```
SELECT C.CLIENTID,
    SUM(NVL(B.FEE, 0)) AS TICKETS,
    SUM(NVL(PU.QTY, 0) * NVL(P.PRICE, 0)) AS MERCH,
    SUM(NVL(B.FEE, 0) + (NVL(P.PRICE, 0) * NVL(PU.QTY, 0))) AS Total
FROM CLIENT C
    LEFT JOIN BOOKINGS B ON B.CLIENTID = C.CLIENTID
    LEFT JOIN PURCHASE PU ON PU.CLIENTID = C.CLIENTID
    LEFT JOIN PRODUCT P ON PU.PRODUCTID = P.PRODUCTID
GROUP BY C.CLIENTID
ORDER BY C.CLIENTID ASC;
```